# Can't get Dropzone.js to work? files always show with red x

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am trying to get dropzone.js to work but with no success.
I have added the dropzone.css and dropzone.js

The plugin can be found at http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Here is my div:

```
<div id="divDropZone" class="dropzone square" style=" width:430px; heigh:300px; background-color:white; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;"></div>
```

Here is my JS

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#divDropZone", { url: "/file/post"});
```

What happens now is the dropzone is displayed but when i drag or browse the item is always shown with a red x and an error on my page:

```
> POST http://localhost:2627/file/post net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Comment: Can you post me the log of your server after you upload?

Comment: this is a server side issue.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to diagnose what's wrong. Follow [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098652/dropzone-js-with-onetime-submit-button/30879057#30879057) to learn how to view the full error when the file is uploaded.

Remember, dropzone uses AJAX, so to see the errors you'll need to use a tool like firebug or crome dev tools. In chrome tools you can use the network panel to view the error. Just look for the dropzone item in red text. Then you'll know what the error is, and should be able to fix it quickly.